# Predefined macros for method names

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, c-preprocessor

In C++ there are predefined macros such as `__FUNCTION__`, which compile to a string literal of the function name the macro is used in.

```
void MyFunc()
{
    printf("I'm in %s!", __FUNCTION__); // I'm in MyFunc!
}
```

Is there anything similar for C#?  I am looking to do this for asp.net web forms:

```
public string MyProperty
{
    get { return (string)ViewState[__PROPERTY__]; }
    set { ViewState[__PROPERTY__] = value; }
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work (otherwise I wouldn't ask the question), I would like to know if there's something similar in C# that doesn't use reflection or have any negative performance impacts versus using a string literal `"MyProperty"`.

This will hopefully cut down on typos on my end, but I can think of a few other instances where this would be useful.

Comment: From my experience with C# you can have macros such as #if debug #endif. However, you cannot have compile time macros that hold anything.

Comment: `__FUNCTION__` _used to_ compile to a string literal (I think in **gcc 2.96**), but it hasn't for many years. The change was a bit painful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [StackTrace and StackFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.getmethod.aspx) to get the name of the current method

```
StackTrace st = new StackTrace(); 
StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(1);
string method = sf.GetMethod().ToString();
```

For properties, the returned method name will include the magic `get_` or `set_` prefixes.

However, I don't think you can really refactor this into an inline macro or function like you could in C++. But if you do refactor a utility method to DRY this out, you could probably just pop the StackTrace back one step to log the caller's information?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm looking for something more performant, and preferably something that happens compile time.

Comment: @Matthew It wouldn't really be *useful* at compile time, since you don't have compile time defines of non-literal values, as you do in C++.  You could just as easily type out the actual method name as you could this identifier...That said, you could always write a visual studio macro to do a replace of `__FUNCTION__` with method name, if you're a good scripter.

Comment: Could one use this in an error handling function with `GetFrame(2)` to get the name of the caller? That would seem more useful, and would perform in the sense that it only happens if needed!

Answer (score 5):

C#'s preprocessor doesn't support macros with associated values like C++, but what you're trying to do can be done with compilers that support C# 5.0 and greater (so at least VS2012+) through compiler generated [Caller Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx). Specifically, via the *CallerMemberNameAttribute* from the *System.Runtime.CompilerServices* namespace. Based on your question's code, I created the following example to illustrate how you could go about doing what you want to do:

```
using System;

class ViewState
{
    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get { return propertyName; }
        set { }
    }
};
class View
{
    ViewState mState = new ViewState();

    static string GetCallerName(
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
    {
        return memberName;
    }

    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return (string)mState[GetCallerName()]; }
        set { mState[GetCallerName()] = value; }
    }
};
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var view = new View();
        Console.WriteLine(view.MyProperty);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
};
```

"MyProperty" will be printed to the console. When compiling, the compiler will replace the default value of GetCallerName's memberName argument with the the calling construct's (property, method, etc) name. So there's no code maintenance needed by the programmer

It should also be noted that this has the added benefit of being able to play nice with obfuscation tools, so long as they happen post-compilation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is something like a `ViewBag` in ASP.NET WebForms. Just in case there isn't, it isn't to difficult to roll you own. You can then wrap the `ViewState` in that class and get regular property member access like you wish.

```
public class ExpandoViewState : DynamicObject
{
    private readonly StateBag _viewState;

    public ExpandoViewState(StateBag viewState)
    {
        _viewState = viewState;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = _viewState[binder.Name];
        if (result != null)
            return true;
        return base.TryGetMember(binder, out result);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        _viewState[binder.Name] = value;
        return true;
    }
}

...

dynamic state = new ExpandoViewState(ViewState);
var val = (string)state.MyProperty;
state.MyProperty = "hi";
```